# mongodb string to number

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have document in mongodb 2.6.11 including array of string i.e.

```
{ cpu: [ '0', '2', '4', '0', '0', '2', '0', '4', '0' ],
 con: [ '232', '2396', '17082', '339', '5', '1738', '503', '4', '0' ] }
```

How do I convert them to numbers without saving in actual collection so I can use them in $project (aggregation) and later use in $group to calculate $avg?

```
db.checkpointstest3.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$cpu"}])
```

I have correct $group , but it works on numbers not strings

Answer (score 2):

Currently the aggregation pipeline does not allow for type conversion, see this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6203) ticket. If changing the type of your field is not an option, you either have to fall back on a map reduce query or write your own aggregation using `forEach`.